# Использование слова "за"

Tags: грамматика

Хотелось бы понять как правильно говорить:

1. Я абсолютно за это решение.
2. Я абсолютно "за" за это решение.
3. Я абсолютно поддерживаю это решение.

На мой взгляд, в первом варианте, в зависимости от того, как читатель интерпретирует слово "за", будет либо непонятно что такое "быть абсолютным за какое-то решение", либо будет чувствоваться отсутствие связи между первой и второй частью предложения.

Второй вариант, я считаю, плохо звучит из-за повторения "за".

Comment: Я не вижу большой проблемы с первым вариантом (мне кажется, он будет однозначно понятен любому носителю языка). В то же время, и первый и третий варианты звучат слегка "неуклюже" исключительно потому, что "абсолютно" редко употребляется в данном контексте (больше похоже на кальку с английского absolutely). Как отметил Баян Купи-ка, "целиком и полностью" звучит намного более органично.

Comment: @ArthurKazykhanov, вариант с калькой вполне возможен, так как судя по Гуглу, такая фраза использовалась пользователями сайтов по иммиграция.

Comment: @ArthurKazykhanov, а насчет "целиком и полностью" — да, с этим выражением предложение лучше звучит, спасибо.

Comment: Вариант №2 предпочтителен (вне зависимости от использования "абсолютно"), если подразумевается, что должно быть голосование.

Comment: @Alexander вариант 2 грамматически неверен. Сомневаюсь, что существует предложение, в котором ЗА должно было бы повторяться два раза подряд (выделение ЗА кавычками сути не меняет).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

По-моему, приемлем вариант **3.** При желании использовать "за" существуют фразеологизмы

> Я **`целиком и полностью за`** это решение
>
> Я **`обеими руками за`** это решение

хотя тут, как мне кажется, есть проблема с ритмикой, вызванная необходимостью интонационно акцентировать подряд все три элемента **`за это решение`**, которая не возникает, если после "за" следует дополнение, состоящее только из одного слова, т.е. **`за это.`** или **`за решение, которое...`**, где акцент на **`за`** не напрашивается.

Фактически **`я абсолютно за`** - это вариация на тему фразеологизмов, тем не менее она звучит несколько неуклюже.

Или можно просто перефразировать предложение:

> Что касается этого решения, (то) я целиком и полностью <sup>обеими руками</sup> "ЗА" / я — "ЗА" целиком и полностью

Comment: Большое спасибо!